# Django Rest get file from FileField url

Tags: python, django, rest, django-views, django-rest-framework

I have created a django rest model which includes a FileField.

```
 media = models.FileField(upload_to='media/%Y/%m/%d/', null=True, blank=True)
```

I also implemented serializer and ListCreateApiView. There I can able to upload a file. On POST request rest server uploads the file in folder and  returns me the url. However, on get request, server return json content with the url. If I use the url for get request, server respond *Page Not Found*. How to download the uploaded file using django rest? Do I have to create separate view for the same? If so, how to do that?

**Edit:**

The resulting url is

```
http://localhost:8000/message/media/2015/12/06/aa_35EXQ7H.svg
```

Comment: Did you define `MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT`? Could you show us what your url looks like? and which server do you use?

Comment: I have not defined MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT. Is it necessary to define?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to define `MEDIA_ROOT`, `MEDIA_URL` and register `MEDIA_URL` in `urlpatterns` to allow Django server to serve these files.

Follow these steps:

`settings.py` file:

```python
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media_root")
```

Append this in your main `urls.py` file to serve media files :

```python
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Also, you don't have to add `media` again in `upload_to` attribute because it's prepended by `MEDIA_URL`, then the url will be `/media/media/`.

Here is a correct example:

```python
media = models.FileField(upload_to='message/%Y/%m/%d/', null=True, blank=True)
```

and the url of the media will be:

```python
http://localhost:8000/media/message/2015/12/06/aa_35EXQ7H.svg
```