# How to convert file path to url in django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I want to convert the file path to url in django project. How can I convert the file field into url?

Comment: There's not nearly enough detail here. What file path? What URL do you want to end up with? What relationship would a file path have with a URL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without further configuration, files stored via Django's `models.FileField` (also `models.ImageField`) end up in your `MEDIA_ROOT` folder and will be available under the base path defined by `MEDIA_URL` using the folder structure under `MEDIA_ROOT`.

Have a look at:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/file-uploads/
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#media-root
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#media-url
- [Django MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517950/django-media-url-and-media-root)
- [Django Rest get file from FileField url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34100743/django-rest-get-file-from-filefield-url)

When the configuration is correct, in your template the link to the file is

```
<a href="{{ object.file.url }}">Download File</a>
```

---

If this question is about static files, search for `static` and `staticfiles` in the Django documentation. It is similar to the media configuration.

---

EDIT: updated links