# How to return array of urls in django

Tags: django, django-urls

There are some files in a directory, and I want to return url of every file in the directory. How can i do that in django ?

```
dir_id_1
-->img1.png
-->img2.png
-->img3.png
dir_id_2
-->img4.png
```

When user send a get request to correspond endpoint with the directory name, It should return urls of images. Something like this.

```
[10.10.10.10:8000/.../dir_id_1/img1.png, 10.10.10.10:8000/.../dir_id_1/img2.png, 10.10.10.10:8000/.../dir_id_1/img2.png]
```

PS: I am keeping these images in filesystem, not in db.

Comment: its good to ask where you're stuck while solving the problem not the solution of the problem itself. Try yourself and if you're facing any particular problem then update the same question.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the whole files and directories in which you store the images using syntax like this, then you can map the entries and edit them using the URL pattern for images

```
import os
entries = os.listdir('[directory_name]/')
```

Answer (score 0):

if you keep images in some directory located on your server you can get them by their path in your domain

```py
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile

path_name = "your/dir/path/name"

def get_urls_in_dir(pathname):
    hostname = Site.objects.get_current().domain
    file_urls = []
    for file in listdir(path_name):
        file_urls.append(hostname + "/" + pathname + "/" + file)
    return file_urls
```

You will get something like

```py
[
    'example.com/dir_id_1/img1.png',
    'example.com/dir_id_1/img2.png',
    'example.com/dir_id_1/img3.png',
]
```

**But it is not good approach**

If you use Django it is better to use `ImageField()` with `MEDIA_URL`, which will keep images on directory you will specify in `MEDIA_URL`, and only store **image path** in your database. By adopting this method you can just get required image by

```
image_object.url
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34117821/8913600) is good example of configuring `MEDIA_URL`